# How to open different pages of a website on github

Tags: html, github, github-pages

So i have deployed my project on Github. It is a web development project. All my html files are in a repo folder including index.html with the link as `username.github.io/projectName/` . When i am opening my repo Github page, the index.html opens up but when I click on any button, it redirects to `username.github.io/webpageName` . I had linked the button using `href = /webpageName.html` . Even my scripts/ css/ images are not loading because of this. Even though `username.github.io/projectName/webpageName` is working but i want it automatic and not by changing the codes. How can i do it?

Comment: "*…i want it automatic and not by changing the codes. How can i do it?*" You cannot. No way.

Answer (score -1):

Are you using .htaccess file?

If yes, then check if your .htaccess file have some errors or not.

If no, then change your href url to your github repo page url's
For example: from

```
`href = /webpageName.html` to 
`href = https://github.com/<user_name>/<repo_name>/<file_name>`
```

Just like that

Comment: I hope this will help you

Comment: GitHub Pages don't use `.htaccess`. See https://pages.github.com/